# Docker make local container available for other containers

Tags: docker

I have two local Docker containers `container_a` and `container_b`.

When starting `container_b`, `container_b` calls `docker pull container_a`. However, this fails as `container_a` is a local container and not hosted on a Docker registry such as Docker Hub.

Is it possible to let `container_b` use the locally available containers when calling `docker pull` without changing `container_b` and without uploading `container_a` to a Docker registry?

Comment: Why don't you use [docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/)?

Comment: @SaschaDoerdelmann Using docker-compose is a possibility but how do I solve the issue using docker-compose?

Comment: You don't need to pull it if it's already local. If you're sharing your docker socket correctly, it should be the same as running the docker cli on the host and local images should be available. The docker cli is fundamentally a rest client for the docker installation running on the host, and this should be true even if running in a container. Still, you're probably doing the wrong thing by running docker in docker -- that's a very rare requirement.

Comment: @SoftwareEngineer Running docker in docker is implemented in the utilized project that provides `container_b`. By sharing the docker socket, `container_b` shows `container_a` when executing `docker images`, but `docker pull container_a` still fails as `container_a` is not on a docker registry.

Comment: You don't need to pull it. It's already there.

Comment: The `docker pull` is executed by `container_b` which I cannot change. Thus, `docker pull` will always be executed. It seems like I have to work with a (local) repository.

Comment: That sounds like a bug in the `container_b` code, which you've trusted with unrestricted access to the entire host filesystem.  If you can't modify the code, what is your programming-related problem?

Answer (score 1):

Mount local docker.sock to your container_b that pulls the image.

```
docker run -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock ...
```

Comment: By sharing the docker socket, `container_b` shows `container_a` when executing `docker images`, but `docker pull container_a` still fails as `container_a` is not on a docker registry.

Comment: @brnk yes pull will strill fail. Other way can be to copy/mount container_a Dockerfile in the container_b and build container_a image in container_b with that. Iff container_a image dependencies are available on docker registry.